# find <li> on click event- jQuery

Tags: jquery

```js
$(function() {
$('#topSearchButton').on("click", function () {
    $('li[type*="COMPANY"],li[type*="BRANCH"],li:contains("Companies"), li:contains("Branch")').toggle("fast");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="topSearchButton" type="button" class="btn" value="click me">
<ul>
    <li><h3>Companies</h3></li>
    <li type="COMPANY">company1</li>
    <li type="COMPANY">company2</li>
    <li type="COMPANY">company3</li>
    <li><h3>Branches</h3></li>
    <li type="BRANCH">branch1</li>
    <li type="COMPANY">branch2</li>
    <li><h3>Documents</h3></li>
    <li type="Documents">Documents1</li>
    <li type="Documents">Documents2</li>
</ul>
```

This code works but I am wondering if is there a better or more efficient way to find elements?

Comment: It is unclear what your requirements are: Do you want to hide all `li` elements, or just certain ones? If you don't want to hide then all then what are the rules?

Comment: I wanto to hide only elements which contains Branches or companies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. you can rather find all the child li elements in next ul of clicked button except one with type documents and that do not contains documents using `:not` selector and then show hide them:

```
$('#topSearchButton').on("click", function () {
   $('li:not([type="Documents"],:contains(Documents))',$(this).next()).toggle("fast");
});
```

**### Working Demo**

Comment: I demonstrated simple solution there will be also different elements for example "Documents" and when I click button I want to toggle everything except "Documents"

Comment: looks interesting I will try now

Comment: This will also hide the "Documents" `h3` which wouldn't make sense

Comment: I have updated this code based on my code and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would add a class to any elements that you want to hide. I would also put an id on the `ul` so you don't have any issues with using other `ul` elements on the same page.

```
<input id="topSearchButton" type="button" class="btn" value="click me">
<ul id="target">
    <li class="canhide"><h3>Companies</h3></li>
    <li class="canhide" type="COMPANY">company1</li>
    <li class="canhide" type="COMPANY">company2</li>
    <li class="canhide" type="COMPANY">company3</li>
    <li class="canhide"><h3>Branches</h3></li>
    <li class="canhide" type="BRANCH">branch1</li>
    <li class="canhide" type="COMPANY">branch2</li>
    <li><h3>Documents</h3></li>
    <li type="Documents">Documents1</li>
    <li type="Documents">Documents2</li>
</ul>
```

Then use `find()` to get the correct elements:

```
$('#topSearchButton').on("click", function () {
    $('#target').find('.canhide').toggle('fast');
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/mddLr4w1/1/)

As a side note, I would suggesting using a `type` attribute, instead use a `data-type` attribute which you can get with JQuery:

```
var type = $('selector').data('type');
```